# How can I determine if a frame/image in a video is in night-vision mode using Computer Vision/Image Processing in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

My input video was sourced from a smart CCTV camera that automatically goes into night-vision mode when it gets dark enough.

I would like to determine if a frame/image in the video I am processing using open-cv (cv2) was a frame/image that was in night-vision mode.

Unfortunately, the shape of each frame/image is (1920,1080,3) even it still switched to night-vision mode which means it's still in RGB channel (3 channels).

Are there ways I can achieve what I intend to achieve?

I would like to thank you in advance for taking time to think and answer to my question.

I cannot find other approaches aside from looking at the number of channels per frame/image.

Here is a sample image showing the difference of a video frame/image in normal and night-vision mode:

[normal-vs-night-vision-mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAG85.png)

Comment: It would help if you provided samples of daytime and nighttime images.

Comment: Hi, Mark Setchell. Thank you for your suggestion. I currently don't have an example for daytime and nighttime frame/images but instead, here is an image showing the difference between the frame/image in normal mode (lights on) and in night-vision mode (lights off). I edited my question, kindly refer to it to see the difference.

Comment: So you want to see if the image has color or not? Are there always colored things in the frame or is it possible that it’s looking at a colorless scene in daytime mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your night-mode images are 3-channel the same as your day-mode images, but look grey, then the likelihood is that your camera has an infra-red (or other) single channel (greyscale) sensor and, when active at night, the single channel is just duplicated into the other two empty channels before being sent to your app by the camera.

You can test this by looking at the first, or any other pixel and seeing if the R, G and B channels are all equal, For example, looking at the first pixel:

```
# {Print all three RGB channels of pixel at [0,0]
print(im[0,0,:])
```

If they are all the same, it will appear grey. If your camera is recording in colour, they are unlikely to be equal.

So, to test an *entire* frame, you could use `numpy.allclose()` to see if the Reds are close to the Greens and the Greens are close to the Blues:

```
Reds   = im[:, :, 0]
Greens = im[:, :, 1]
Blues  = im[:, :, 2]
nightmode = np.allclose(Reds, Greens, atol=2.0) and np.allclose(Greens, Blues, atol=2.0)
```

I put in a tolerance of 2 on the brightnesses being equal, to allow for some deviation from being 100% identical - though I am not sure how this could possibly come about.

Comment: Hi, Mark Setchell. After observing the result of what you instructed me to do, it seems true. The values in each channel are the same when the IR night-vision mode is triggered but not for all the pixels.

Regardless, the code you provided worked as intended. I would like to try it to a video with different setting (e.g., lighting, brightness, place, etc.) to further verify it. (break.)

Comment: (cont.) May I ask if I should modify (or not) the conditional to determine if the Reds and Blues channel matrices are close to each other with this:

`nightmode = np.allclose(Reds, Greens, atol=2.0) and np.allclose(Greens, Blues, atol=2.0) and np.allclose(Reds, Blues, atol=2.0)`

If not, may I ask the reason why?

Thank you again, for responding to my question. Your initial answer really helped.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. If the Reds are close to the Greens and the Greens are close to the Blues, it follows that the Reds and Blues are pretty close too, i.e. less than 4 apart.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks again for your answer, Mark Setchell. I'll try to follow up in this thread if it works fine with videos from another setup so that others can apply it to their project.

Comment: Hi, Mark Setchell. I was just curious, where or how did you know that the single channel is being copied to other channels when it comes to videos from a camera with IR sensor?

Comment: It's normal to use an IR/thermal sensor for night-vision and they are only sensitive to a single IR frequency. If they want to send 3-channel RGB images and IR images, the obvious thing to do is to duplicate the same channel into all three and it will just look grey since its red, green and blue components are equal. It's fairly common.

Comment: Interesting. Are there other ways or mechanisms on how night-vision works? Perhaps other than how IR/thermal sensors. If yes, do they perform the same mechanism (channel copying) if in night-vision mode?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the camera provides an API, that gives that information, you won't be sure.
Plus "night vision mode" covers many different things.

Sometimes (but you would know it. It cost a fortune, plus, in many country, selling is restricted because it is considered a weapon) it is real night vision (with MCP tubes and all). I am not aware tho, of such camera that could "switch" to night vision mode. The one I know of do that single thing, and don't have RGB channel. But well, if it were, one idea for such camera could be to detect the "chicken fence" (they are very static in the image. So a simple sum of pixels in a pre-learn position of the chicken fence should do).

For some other cameras, it is really a change of sensor, to switch to a non-color sensor with a wide spectrum. And then RGB channels are just 3 copies of the same thing. You just have to detect that

Some other times, night vision means simply that infrared leds have been switch on. Most camera can see in infrared. Unwillingly. But yet, that can be useful, since that means that, by night, a scene lighted by infrared light would be visible. You can check with your smartphone camera and the remote controller of your TV: you can't see the infrared led of your tv with your naked eye, but through your phone camera, it is like a led was blinking.

In such case, it is still the same camera. The pixels really are in color. Just, no color are visible in the real scene, lighted only by IR (a little bit like if you were lighting your scene only by a green light, then, the camera is still RGB, but you can't see colors. Only level of green)

It is even worse if this occurs progressively. So if at some point, more and more of the light come from IR, and less and less from the fading real light.

What I would try (but I can't say more without any example) is something like a cosine similarity between the channels. Chance are that RGB channels are different by day, and more similar by night (in other words, by night image seem more monochrome). So some

`(img[:,:,0].astype(float)*img[:,:,1].astype(float)).sum()/np.sqrt((img[:,:,0].astype(float)**2).sum()*(img[:,:,1].astype(float)**2).sum())`

(using here only 2 channels. But that could be repeated with channels 0 and 2, and/or with channels 1 and 2)

And see if that values tends to vary between day and night. And find the threshold by experiment.

Comment: Hi, chrslg. Your explanation of possible mechanisms for night-vision mode in cameras helped me a lot. The camera I am using is from TP Link, their Tapo TC70 smart surveillance camera and I confirmed from its website stating that: 


"The 850 nm infrared night vision supports automatic color switch filter in low light conditions with a visual distance of up to 30 ft."

(I'll continue my reply on the next comment due to character limit)

Comment: (continuation)
I tried using the code you provided wherein the results displayed 1.0 when it switched to night-vision mode and below 1.0 otherwise. I will verify it if it's good enough as an indicator by trying videos/footages with different settings (e.g., place, brightness, and lighting).

Also, it seems that code you provided seeks to find the cosine similarity between Red(0) and Green(1) channels. May I ask the reason why you omitted the Blue(3) channel?

I hope for your response and I would like to thank you again for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: By the way, here are some samples of the cosine similarity per video frame/image displayed on the terminal based on the code your provided:

0.999965983860202
0.9999996968074304
0.9999997628020663
0.9999997940455051
0.9999998043128675
0.9999998059599096
0.9999998005362738
0.9999997787786613
0.9999997593523463
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0

Comment: That's a lot of 9. But there are a lot anyway. I've tested also on images I found on google images (some screenshots of images by night and by day from the same camera). And it is something like 0.98 for color (day) images, vs 0.999 for night images. Which surprised me (I expected less than 0.98 for day images). But only a little. Because obviously, in a color image, there is a correlation between components. What is dark in red is more likely to be also dark in blue. It is usual to read that 70% of information is in black and white. Or more. That is one of the reasons for

Comment: the way analog TV (NTSC, PAL, SECAM) encode YUV with U and V being only half (some times even 1/3) of the payload. That is color is quite a small addition to the main component that is grayscale. Cosine similarity, as name suggest, should be interpreted as an "angle" between 2 vectors (so that even if one is twice brighter than the other, they are still 100% similar if they are the same, to a positive multiplicative factor). So it might be easier for human reasoning to observe the arccos (of those numbers).

Comment: As for why I've used only `[:,:,0]` and `[:,:,1]`, that was what I meant by _using here only 2 channels. But that could be repeated with channels 0 and 2, and/or with channels 1 and 2_. I compared only cosine similarity between red and green in my example, because I was lazy. But it would be better so also use green. For example with a formula such as `cosim(img[:,:,0],img[:,:,1])+cosim(img[:,:,0],img[:,:,2])+cosim(img[:,:,1],img[:,:,2])`. 3 being "monochrome image", and then the smaller the number, the more color in the image. (`cosim` here being the expression I've shown)

Comment: Thanks again, chrslg. I tried doing what you mentioned, and it still also worked as intended. Here are some samples of the summation of cosine similarity among the frame/image channels: 2.999993799364195
2.9999930953781244
2.999991770589016
2.999989535149074
3.0
3.0
3.0. The summation becomes exactly 3.0 when the frame/image generated from the moment the camera switched to night-vision mode. I would like to verify this if it works with other videos with different setting. But I think this also does the job as of now.

Comment: Yes. I see that you've accepted the other answer, so I guess it works. Which means that cosine similarity is overkill. Because the camera simply copies the channel 3 times when it is in nightmode. So it is an exact copy. My method firstly would have been useful if channels were "roughly equal" by night, and "less equal" by day. Secondly, my method is also useful when channels are not only "almost" equal, but that almost equal is "to a factor". So for example, when the image is a sepia monochrome image: R,G,B are almost proportional to each other, but not equal (B is less than R and G).

Comment: So in your case, obviously (otherwise the `np.close` method would not have worked at all), channels are just equal when in night mode. So no need for subtleties like cosine similarity. Go with `np.close`. And probably `==` would have worked as well (`(img[:,:,0]==img[:,:,1]).all()`). You could even probably subsample (if == works, then it is unlikely that even 100 random pixels are exactly ==). So `(img[::8,::8,0]==img[::8,::8,1]).all()` may work (and is 64 times faster)

Comment: Hi, chrslg. I tried both of your suggestions, and they worked like charms. Maybe I would stick to having no subsampling just to make sure. But if I really need to make my project faster, maybe I could cut corners by resorting to that. I would like to accept your answer as well, but I can only accept one. But thanks again for your further effort. I really appreciate it. For those who might stumble upon this, try considering the aforementioned approach(es).

Comment: No need to accept 2 answers. Mark's answer was the correct one. Mine would have been useful for other cameras, but not for yours :)